# How does electromagnetism factor into inductively coupled RFID systems

Tags: rfid, inductive

LF and HF RFID systems use inductive coupling to supply the tag with power.

UHF RFID systems use antennas to send electromagnetic waves, the power supplied to the tag comes from the transmitted power of the tx antenna.

As far as I understood, there are no electromagnetic waves used in LF and HF RFID systems, is that correct? In certain literature they are grouped together as an explanation for the skin effect was given as

"An electromagnetic wave impinging on a conductive object penetrates to an extend known as the skin-depth.... It is apparent that at 125 kHz, water and water-containing materials have essentially no effect on RFID Operation"

But 125 kHz is in the LF category so it uses inductive coupling instead of electromagnetic waves.

Comment: Inductively coupled RFID readers consist of a RLC circuit tuned to resonance frequency to increase efficiency. So they actually do generate electromagnetic waves but they dont use backscatter to modulate reverse link signals. The power for the tag comes from the change of magnetic field from the reader coil which has an electric field component.

Comment: That doesn't sound entirely true...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question: Yes, it is correct that there are no EM waves used in HF and LF RFID systems. They rely solely on magnetic field coupling.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What does the frequency (for example 13.56 MHz for HF) refer to if there are no EM waves used? Is it the frequency of the magnetic field?

Comment: Yes, its the frequency of the magnetic field.

Comment: Its not true that there is no electrical field involved with RFID systems. Its just not used.